# jsPDF custom page size setting broken in version 1.5.3

Tags: jspdf

I have a code to set custom page size for a pdf document in jsPDF version 1.4.1. I upgraded the jsPDF library to version 1.5.3 and see that the custom page size setting is badly broken.

I found out that there is a commit 
https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF/commit/651dbfbaea3c8f4b07093c23ac2bdc53c1c4c22a?diff=split

that resolves the issue i was talking about. I added that fix in my local jsPDF 1.5.3 code and see that issue is resolved.

We see that the version 1.5.3 is the latest released version and that does not include the fix. 
How can we get this fix ?